# Meu Crystal Report sempre aparece em branco

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Utilizo Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate e a última versão do Crystal Reports.

Mas sempre que executo a página, mesmo no localhost o relatório vem em branco.
Ao exibir o código-fonte da página consigo ver toda a informação da mesma.
Ele apenas não joga essa informação em forma de relatório. Alguma ideia?

**Aspx**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{            
    ReportDocument rptrel = new ReportDocument();
    rptrel.Load(Server.MapPath("Rel_ComissaoInadCanc.rpt"));    
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptrel;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Sem ver o seu código ou algo assim, fica difícil para adivinhar o que está acontecendo contigo, não acha?

Comment: Acabei de jogar o código!

No Visual Studio eu consigo enxergar ele normalmente no design.
Mas quando executo e vai para o localhost, ele gera em branco.
Mesmo enviando dados para a página.

Comment: Faz um teste trocando `ReportDocument rptrel = new ReportDocument();
       rptrel.Load(Server.MapPath("Rel_ComissaoInadCanc.rpt"));` por `ReportDocument rptrel = new Rel_ComissaoInadCanc();`

Comment: Ou, você ainda pode tentar, `ReportDocument rptrel = new ReportDocument(); rptrel.Load("Caminho do relatorio");`

Comment: Alterei como informou, mas continua vindo em branco.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi esse problema jogando a pasta ***aspnet_client*** dentro do diretório onde o IIS lê o projeto.

Dentro desta pasta está o ***crystalreportsviewers*** que carrega o relatório. No meu caso, era isso que fazia a tela vir em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]